# Manipulating the DOM in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to learn React lately and have a question about direct DOM manipulation.  I'm working on a project where upon page load, a logo slides in from the side.  I can accomplish this in vanilla javascript, but this particular project is in React.  I'm wondering if it is okay to do the following?  Or if there is a preferred way to do it in React?

I have the following function:

```
logoSlideIn() {
  const logo = this.refs.logo;
  logo.classList.add("z-logo-reveal");
}
```

In the componentDidMount method, I have:

```
setTimeout(this.logoSlideIn, 500);
```

The corresponding CSS is:

```
.z-logo {
  position: relative;
  background: url(z-logo.svg) bottom center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 35%;
  width: 50%;
  left: 1800px;
  transition: 4s ease-in-out;
}


.z-logo-reveal {
  left: 0;
}
```

It works, but is there a better way?

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? Is it something like you want to change the way the css class is added? Or what else? Your question is not clear on what exactly you need from us

Comment: I’m mostly looking for clarification on what it means when I hear that in React, you don’t want to manipulate the DOM directly.  Would the above constitute manipulating the DOM directly? And if so, what is the alternative?  Or does it not really matter in the above scenario?

Answer (score 2):

In react it's very rarely when you really need to manipulate the DOM directly. usually is considered not a good practice, for your particular case I'd recommend using props to assign the new className, for example:

```
state = {
  animateCls: '',
};

componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => this.setState({ animateCls: 'z-logo-reveal'}), 500);
}

render() {
  const { animateCls } = this.state;

  return (
    <div className={animateCls}>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you have is fine, you can also do it by setting `props`, it'll be similar.